# Unable to select finish when creating new gradle project in eclipse

Tags: windows, eclipse, gradle, environment-variables, eclipse-oxygen

I'm unable to import or create a gradle project in Eclipse Oxygen. In either case when I get to the final screen and try to select "finish", it does nothing. I've got some screenshots below to help understand what the issue is. I believe my environment variables are set correctly because I was able to run java -version and gradle -version from cmd. When I get to the final screen for importing/creating gradle project, the Java home directory, Gradle version, and Gradle user home directory are unknown.

Here's what i'm working with

- Windows 10  java
- java version "9.0.4"
- Gradle 4.5.1

**Screenshots**

- [Importing Gradle Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uT4tt.png)
- [JRE Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYC2a.png)
- [New Gradle Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUOM9.png)

Answer (score 6):

So what ended up fixing this issue was going into the Eclipse Marketplace -> installed and then updating the Buildship Gradle Integration 2.0 plugin. Hope this helps someone

Comment: Thanks, this save my day. My case is hold on task init.